# Custom SVG Map | Performance Issues

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, maps

Building an interactive map and running into severe performance issues specifically around zooming. When the user tries to zoom it's jittery or better put, not smooth.

The library being used to handle the zoom is: https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom

The map renders 1100 individual SVG elements that are 6 X 9 in dimensions so relatively small and off the bat that already seems like the issue.

For confidential reasons I can't share the design of the map but imagine a map that is cartoon like to outline a campsite. It contains trees, gradients, many campsites hence the high number in elements.

I can't find much information an issue relative to this let alone SVG performance.

Any suggestions on how to improve performance would be greatly appreciated.

Additional information, the application is built with React JS, Redux, Webpack, ES6.